# C - Memory leak even with all allocs free'd

Tags: c, memory-leaks, getline

My program basically gets user input and compares words that are anagrams of eachother. I've compiled the program in Unix and ran valgrind -v against it, however I'm not understanding where my memory leak can be coming from when all heap allocations are free'd at exit.  Here is my main method and valgrind output.

```
int main()
{
    // Create a head node for the linked list, and a newNode variable to 
    //add to the list     
    struct node *newNode;
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory. Exiting.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    head->next = NULL;

    // For user input
    char *input = NULL;
    char *data;
    size_t len = 0;

    // Read a line in at a time
    while(getline(&input, &len, stdin) != EOF)
    {
        // Delete newline symbol
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
        // Convert string to seperate words
        data = strtok(input, " ");

        // While there are more words from the sentence to read
        while(data != NULL)
        {
            // Check that its a letter
            int i, check = 0, length = strlen(data);
            for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if(isalpha(data[i]) == 0)
                {
                    check = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If a letter, create a node, set the data, and append to the
            // to the linked list
            if(check == 0)
            {
                newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                if(newNode == NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory. Exiting.\n");
                    return 1;
                }

                newNode->data = data;
                newNode->next = NULL;

                if(head->next == NULL)
                {
                    head->next = newNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    struct node *current = head;
                    while(current->next != NULL){
                        current = current->next;
                    }

                    current->next = newNode;
                }
            }
            // If not a letter, skip the node creation and output error
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Bad word %s\n", data);
            }

            data = strtok(NULL, " ");

        }

        input = NULL;
        data  = NULL;
    }

    print_anagrams(head->next);
    // Free all mallocs and pointers
    free(newNode);
    free(head);
    free(input);
    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Valgrind output

```
==32070== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==32070==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-
amd64-linux.so)
==32070==    by 0x400F43: main (anagrams2.c:192)
==32070==  Address 0x51fc1f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==32070==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-
amd64-linux.so)
==32070==    by 0x400F0F: main (anagrams2.c:187)
==32070==
==32070==
==32070== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32070==     in use at exit: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==32070==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 288 bytes allocated
==32070==
==32070== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==32070== Checked 80,264 bytes
==32070==
==32070== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==32070==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind
/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32070==    by 0x4EA5F54: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:66)
==32070==    by 0x400EF9: main (anagrams2.c:131)
==32070==
==32070== LEAK SUMMARY:
==32070==    definitely lost: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==32070==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32070==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32070==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32070==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32070==
==32070== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==32070==
==32070== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==32070== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==32070==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-
amd64-linux.so)
==32070==    by 0x400F43: main (anagrams2.c:192)
==32070==  Address 0x51fc1f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==32070==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-
amd64-linux.so)
==32070==    by 0x400F0F: main (anagrams2.c:187)
==32070==
==32070== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: If you are using `getline` and you see "`in use at exit: 120 bytes in 1 blocks`", then that should clue you into the fact that you are failing to free (or otherwise misusing) the buffer allocated by `getline` (`input` in  your case). The default allocation size for the `getline` buffer is `120-bytes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. You should not be freeing `data` as it is returned from call to `strtok` and is not a malloced pointer and is just a pointer to the string inside of input returned by getline.(This mostly causes your Invalid Free Error in Valgrind Report)
2. You set `input` to NULL at the end of the loop, so you are basically losing the pointer to the memory returned by `getLine`. You should be freeing `input` inside the loop at the appropriate place (This is causing your Memory Leak Error in Valgrind Report)

Comment: Isn't `data` a pointer to a string inside `input` which is `malloc`'ed by `getline`. The problem with freeing it is it may not point to the beginning of the block allocated by `getline`. A good hint to that is `inside a block of size 120` (the default allocation size in `getline`)

Comment: If he just happens to have the `data` point to the first token from `strtok`, he would essentially be freeing `input` (which he should do anyway after duplicating and storing `data` in a separate block of memory). Big rule with `getline`, you cannot lose a reference to the beginning of its allocation of `input` or you lose the ability to free the block allocated by `getline`. Always better to allocate new blocks for storing portions of `input` so that `input` can be left for reuse by `getline` (which it does on subsequent reads).

Comment: Better would be to send a malloced buffer as input to getline. It may resize it if needed. Keep sending the same input pointer for multiple calls and free it after exiting the loop. This also clearly establishes who is the owner of the memory to the reader of the code.

Comment: If you free line, all those data pointers stored in the linked list will be left to dangle.